# I need a running number in a MS Access Query based on a condition

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am looking to generate a Column which is based on a condition
The Column 3 should generate a running number and should start when Column 2 has value > 0

```
Col1 ColM   Col2    Col 3
AA    1      0      0
AA    2      0      0
AA    3      223    1
AA    4      44     2
AA    5      5      3
AA    6      55     4
BB    1      0      0
BB    2      0      0
BB    3     0       0
BB    4      0      0
BB    5      11     1
BB    6      22     2
```

Please help me and thanks in advance for looking into this

Comment: Is there an ID field?

Comment: the ID is col 1 field, but i have a running month number field which is a running number. I have updated my table now

Comment: Do you have a unique id per row?  Or is that the first two columns?

Comment: I dont have unique ID for each row, but i have it for each set which is the month number, So the unique composite key would be Col 1 and Col M

Comment: Bother! I just finished posting my answer. I'll leave it though, for someone else with a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can identify groups of column 2 values that are non-zero by counting the number of zeros that appear *before* the value:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from table as t2
        where t2.col2 = 0 and
              t2.col1 < t.col1 or t2.col1 = t.col1 and t2.colM <= t.colM
       ) as grp
from table as t;
```

Next, you can use this as a subquery to enumerate the rows inside each group.  This is a bit nasty:

```
select t.col1, t.colM, t.col2,
       iif(t.col2 = 0, 0, count(*) - 1) as col3
from (select t.*,
             (select count(*)
              from table as t2
              where t2.col2 = 0 and
                    t2.col1 < t.col1 or t2.col1 = t.col1 and t2.colM <= t.colM
             ) as grp
      from table as t
     ) as t join
     (select t.*,
             (select count(*)
              from table as t2
              where t2.col2 = 0 and
                    (t2.col1 < t.col1 or t2.col1 = t.col1 and t2.colM <= t.colM)
             ) as grp
      from table as t
     ) as tgrp
     on tgrp.grp = t.grp and
        (tgrp.col1 < t.col1 or tgrp.col1 = t.col1 and t2.colM <= t.colM)
group by t.col1, t.colM, t.col2;
```

The logic assigns the preceding 0 to the same group as the values greater than 0.  This is why the `-1` is needed in the `select`.

This would be much easier in most other databases, because they support window functions.

Comment: Damn, that is painful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gordon.. anyways i will try if i dont get any better answers

Comment: @Sathish It might simplify things if you could save the subquery as a separate query (since Access doesn't support CTEs). Or use [`CREATE VIEW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177895(v=office.12).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you can use VBA, add the following code to a module:

```
Dim lastCol1 As String, lastCount As Integer

Function RunningConditionalCount(col1 As String, col2 As Integer) As Integer
    If lastCol1 <> col1 Then
        lastCount = 0
        lastCol1 = col1
    End If
    If col2 > 0 Then lastCount = lastCount + 1
    RunningConditionalCount = lastCount
End Function
```

and call it:

```
SELECT [table].*, RunningConditionalCount(col1,col2) AS Expr1
FROM [table]
ORDER BY table.col1, table.colM;
```

This works because the module-level variables (`lastCol1` and `lastCount`) retain their values between calls.

One gotcha - in your data there is more than one unique value for `Col1`. If there is ever a data set with only one unique value for `Col1`, `lastCol1` will never be reset. If that is a possibility, then you'll have to explicitly reset it, either by creating a `Sub`:

```
Sub Reset()
    lastCol1 = ""
End Sub
```

and calling it in code before you run the query.

Alternatively, you could call the function once with hard-coded values as part of a `UNION` query and then exclude the generated record:

```
SELECT col1, col2, colM, Expr1
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 "" AS Col1, 0 AS ColM, 0 AS Col2, RunningConditionalCount("",0) AS Expr1, 0 AS RowType
    FROM [table]

    UNION ALL SELECT [table].*, RunningConditionalCount(col1,col2) AS Expr1, 1
    FROM [table]
) AS t1
WHERE RowType=1
ORDER BY col1, colM
```